# iOS: 15.4 Beta - Identify if faceid with mask is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, biometrics, face-id

With the new feature enabled in ios beta 15.4, I can validate that faceID with mask works.

We get a bool(matched/unmatched) response when using evaluatePolicy, which is not helpful in finding if faceid-with-mask was used.

I want to disable the face id feature of the app when a non-secure way of authentication is enabled and I'm unable to find any documentation on this on LAPolicy's page.

What would be the recommended way to go around finding if face id with mask is enabled? Any help with documentation would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I highly doubt that there is any way of knowing. If Apple were to provide information on this it would be via an API change and API changes typically only happen with iOS versions - So there might be something in iOS16.   Conceptually there isn't much difference between the user choosing to enable FaceID with mask and using a passcode of 123456 - Both reduce security, both are a user choice and both are not visible to an app using local authentication.

Comment: I've my own passcode, faceid was secure enough to access the secure storage. Face id with mask isn't secure(as mentioned in the dialog after enabling face-id-with-mask) I just want to make sure if faceid-with-mask is enabled I use the passcode.

Comment: I think all you can do is provide an option for the user to use a passcode rather than Face ID if they choose.  I don't think there is any way you can make the decision for them.

Comment: I do have an option to use passcode, I want to make a decision on when to disable faceid(when faceid-mask is enabled) and use the passcode.

Comment: I understand, but what I am saying is that it isn't *your* decision.  It is the user's.  Provide them with an option to use Face ID or passcode.  They can decide if they are happy to use Face ID even with the Mask option is enabled or they only want to use passcode.  It is a good option anyway; Some user may never want to use Face ID for some reason.